# How to return more mysql rows in function?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I want to make a function in PHP to return a list of mysql results. But i want to enter my own tekst also.

When i echo i get the results but i want to return the value.

```
 function Get() {
 $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM blabla");
 $value4 = 'certain';
 while($approw = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

 $value= 'Fun '. $approw['value1'].' '.$approw['value2'].' '.$approw['value3'].'percent '.$value4.'<br />' ;

 }
   return $value.' Powered by Hisenseb';
 }
 ?>
```

In the while the results can change anytime
How can i do this? Can anyone tell me how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $value should be array of your concatenation  strings

Comment: You want one function return the searched rows, and another that does your concat format thing. Split tasks - this way you can re-use them.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a `mysqli::connect()` object to the `Get()` function as an argument, and for example, select a `array` as the return value where you store the result set from the sql query and the text you want. Try it:

```
function Get(mysqli $connect)
{
   $ret = [];
   $value4 = 'certain';

   if ($res = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM blabla")) {
      $row = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $ret['mytext'] = 'Fun '. $row['value1'].' '.$row['value2'].' '.$row['value3'].'percent '.$value4.'<br />' ;
      $ret['result-set'] = $row;
   }
   $connect->close();
   return count($ret) > 0 ? $ret : false;
}
```

Now just call the function:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","database");
$result = Get($conn);

$sql = $result['result-set'];
$mytext = $result['mytext'];

// You can then get the data from the sql table using the column names of your table:

$column1 = $sql['column1']; //Now in $column1 you have the value from the SQL table from column column1.
```